# Active Directory and 3rd party cloud services - security?

Tags: security, active-directory, cloud

Question regarding Active Directory
Scenario: a third party software which is hosted in the cloud offers SSO in connection with the Active Directory that we run in our network.

Silly question, but isn't this a big security risk when granting an external application in the cloud access to the AD in our network? I can see so many applications which support SSO and they are hosted in the cloud but I really have my doubts in regards to security in this case. I'm not an AD expert at all, so you may can enlighten me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your on-premise Active Directory should never be opened up directly to access from the internet. Active Directory maintains symmetric keys for its users that are used in the Kerberos protocol which are very sensitive to leakage.

If an internet hosted application wants to use Active Directory to authenticate users, they can use [federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity). Microsoft provides [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) (a service which you'd run on-premise with ADFS-proxy in the DMZ) or [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis) in the cloud for this.

Comment: Thank you, ADFS it is! - Solved.